# Problem in using async and await in python

Tags: python, async-await

I am trying to using async and await, I am still new to it I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong

```
import requests
import bs4
import colorama
from colorama import Fore
import time
import datetime
import asyncio



async def get_html(episode_number: int) -> str:
    print(Fore.YELLOW + f"Getting HTML for episode {episode_number}", flush=True)

    url = f'https://talkpython.fm/{episode_number}'
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            resp.raise_for_status()
            return await resp.text
    await resp.raise_for_status()
   # return await resp.text


def get_title(html: str, episode_number: int) -> str:
    print(colorama.Fore.CYAN + f"Getting TITLE for episode {episode_number}", flush=True)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    header = soup.select_one('h1')
    if not header:
        return "MISSING"

    return header.text.strip()


def main():

    t0 = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(colorama.Fore.WHITE + ' App started.', flush=True )

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    final_task = asyncio.gather(loop)
    #get_title_range()
    dt = datetime.datetime.now() - t0
    loop.run_until_complete(final_task)
    print(colorama.Fore.CYAN + "Done. " + ' App exiting total time: {:,.2f} sec.'.format(dt.total_seconds()), flush=True)


def get_title_range():
  
    for n in range(150, 170):
        html = get_html(n)
        title = get_title(html, n)
        print(Fore.CYAN + f"Title found: {title}", flush=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: what didn't work? is there any error message? recommended read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not initializing tasks for your event loop to run on. I typically follow this pattern:

```py
async def main():
    headers = {'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': auth}
    url = 'some-api.com/post-request-something'

    # We use a session to take advantage of tcp keep-alive
    timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=10000)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=timeout) as session:
        tasks = [async_wrap(session, q, url, headers) for q in queue]
        # gather literally 'gathers' all the tasks and schedules them in the event loop
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ts = time()
    # Create the asyncio event loop - from the main function
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    finally:
        # Lets avoid an unclosed loop running a DDoS attack on ourselves
        loop.close()
    logger.info('Took %s seconds to complete', time() - ts)
```

note the line containing, takes those tasks gathered to schedule as coroutines in the main event loop:

```py
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

and then this, which calls my function, async_wrap() for each record I wanted to send in the http client (which I had stored in a list), but in your case it would call your asynchronous function get_html() using each record from get_title_range():

```py
tasks = [async_wrap(session, q, url, headers) for q in queue] # -> mine
await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True) # -> gather those tasks!

tasks = [get_html(episode_number=episode) for episode in list_of_episode_nums] # -> yours
await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True) # -> gather those tasks!
```

Hope this helps you shore some details up, but unfortunately, asynchronous code can be quite a headache, requiring lots of trial-and-error.